# Error "Unresolved reference" when listing Views from XML file

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

As you will realise while reading this, I am new to programming, and I am very much stuck.

I have 5 text views in the layout with ID´s "box_one_text , box_two_text" and so on, when I try to set the click listeners on MainActivity, I create a list of items calling for each textView by it's ID:

```kotlin
private fun setListeners(){
    val clickableViews: List<View> =
        listOf(box_one_text, box_two_text, box_three_text, box_four_text,
        box_five_text, constraint_layout)

    for(item in clickableViews){
        item.setOnClickListener { makeColored(it)  }
    }
}
```

Everything inside listOf is an error, calling for the "Unresolved reference" I talked about earlier)

How do I fix this?

Comment: You have to use [findViewById](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#findViewById(int)) or [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Comment: Or you may add this to app gralde `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`, but i would recommend switching to [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), since kotlin synthetics is deprecated now.

Answer (score 3):

I also came across this issue and finally found the answer here:
https://github.com/udacity/andfun-kotlin-color-my-views/issues/11

This is because view binding is missing from our code; to solve this problem, there are 2 solutions.

The simple way is to add the below line to app level Gradle file:

```
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

The other solution is to follow the data binding steps which is discussed here: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud9012/lessons/4f6d781c-3803-4cb9-b08b-8b5bcc318d1c/concepts/68b85cff-8813-496b-86ba-57ed352d8bcf. I'm not sure if you're following the same course as me, but the course I linked is free and it has a similar (highly likely the same) code exercise as yours.

There are some other ideas from the GitHub URL I included above.

Answer (score 0):

`box_one_text, box_two_text, box_three_text, box_four_text, box_five_text, constraint_layout` dont refer to the views directly instead they are just the `IDs` Use `findViewById` to find the required view and later set `OnClickListener`

Try the following

```
val view1 : View = findViewById(R.id.box_one_text)
val view2 : View = findViewById(R.id.box_two_tex)

//pattern follows for the rest of the views too

    val clickableViews: List<View> =
        listOf(view1, view2, view3 ....)

    for(item in clickableViews){
        item.setOnClickListener { makeColored(it)  }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!, this solved the error indeed. Just wondering why the video i´m following doesn´t have the error without calling findViewById or ViewBinding...

Comment: can you send the link to the video?

Comment: It is a paid course, so the video is private... I´ve been trying all the answers, and i´m now sure they used  - apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' - mentioned by rahat.